# visualizing tabulator symbol in a html page

Tags: html

I would like to be able to make tabulator symbols visible in pre area in html. For example to make space visible I replace it with '·' . For tabulator I would like to see a tiny arrow or similar.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: if you mean space you can use `&nbsp;`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing characters for text presentation.

Comment: A `pre` element is effectively an escape from HTML to plain text, and you would have exactly the same issue when presenting data in a plain text file. There are many characters to choose from; and the question does not specify criteria for selecting, say, different arrow characters.

Comment: the question is not about choosing characters, I want to make the tab area visible, not to replace the tab symbol with another. It works with space, because in pre space is represented with the same size any other symbol is. This though is not true for tabulators. A single tabulator could be represented in pre in up to 4/8 characters, depending on the context of the tabulator.

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of limited with the amount of styling you can do since you're working inside a `pre` tag. You can use `.replace()` to replace spaces and tabs in the pre code with something like this:

```
$('pre').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    content = content.replace(/ /g, '.').replace(/\t/g, '----');
    $(this).html(content);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RExZL/3/